# Sitecore Xconnect lock time expire issue

Tags: xconnect

I am using sitecore 9.3 and facing an issue with xconnect when using identifyas in the code to identify the user using the email i got the below exception

> Exception: Sitecore.Analytics.DataAccess.XdbUnavailableException
> Message: xDB unavailable Source: Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect    at
> Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.XConnectDataAdapterProvider.ExecuteWithExceptionHandling[T](Func`2 func)    at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounters.OperationPerformanceMonitorExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<Monitor>b__0() at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounters.OperationPerformanceMonitorExtensions.Monitor[T](OperationPerformanceMonitorBase monitor, Func`1 operation)    at
> Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.StandardSession.IdentifyAs(String source,
> String knownIdentifier)    at
> Authentication.Pipelines.CookieAuthentication.SignedIn.UpdateUserProfile.Process(SignedInArgs
> args)
>
> Nested Exception
>
> Exception: Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException
> Message: {   "Message": "Operation failed: The lock time has expired."
> } Source: Sitecore.XConnect.Client    at
> Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectSynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock(Func`1 taskFactory)    at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.XConnectDataAdapterProvider.<>c__DisplayClass35_0.<ExecuteWithExceptionHandling>b__0(IXdbContext c)    at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.XConnectDataAdapterProvider.ExecuteWithExceptionHandling[T](Func`2
> func)

Comment: It sounds like you have SQL performance issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was related to the time of the SQL server was not correct and was different from that on CD\CM.
Issue is fixed after adjusting the time on SQL server.